# Acumatica: Using FastFilter Fields in Mobile App

Tags: c#, mobile, acumatica

I am runningAcumatica 2022 R2. I have added Fast Filter fields to the Sales Order, on the InventoryID in the Details Tab.

This works (mostly)

The new fields DO show up in the pop up box when you hit the magnifying glass, and I can search on them:

[image: Extra Fastfields]

But two issues remain:

1. They do ***not*** work in the fast lookup at the detail line:

[image: Inline search fails]

2. They do not work in the mobile app:

[image: Android App]

So, how do I fix this?